# Indexing a String

Tags: rust

I want to perform a very simple task, but I cannot manage to stop the compiler from complaining.

```
fn transform(s: String) -> String {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    format!("{}/{}", bytes[0..2], bytes[2..4])
}
```

`[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time.

Some tips making this operation to work as intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the size of a `[u8]` isn't known at compile time. The size of `&[u8]` however is known at compile time because it's just a pointer plus a `usize` representing the length of sequence.

```
format!("{:?}/{:?}", &bytes[0..2], &bytes[2..4])
```

Rust strings are encoded in utf-8, so working with strings in this way is generally a bad idea because a single unicode character may consist of multiple bytes.

Comment: damn thx. Comming from high level languages doenst make me smart i guess.

Comment: feel free to mention anything you would like to have clarified :)